# Check Web Service Availability Before Using HttpClient Methods In Xamarin.Forms (PCL)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am testing my web service (locally) availability before using `HttpClient` Methods

I am using 
my code below working fine when i put the url "google.com" put it does not work when I give my web service url I want to include port number in my url how can I achieve that

```
  if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                bool isRemoteReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("192.168.1.107",3);
                if (!isRemoteReachable)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Server not available", "Please try again later", "OK");
                }
            }
```

Comment: are you sure that IP is reachable from your device/emulator and will respond to a ping?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'http://' prefix to your URL? Maybe you have to specify a port for your URL?

Comment: i just realized that my url has to have port 8733 where can i put it?

Comment: @EvZ How do i put my port number

Comment: bool isRemoteReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("192.168.1.107:8733/Synchronization/rest/getclassesbrief",3); here is my code sample

Comment: read the docs: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [official connectivity plugin documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html) in order to set a port you should call the method in the next way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests if a remote host name is reachable (no http:// or www.)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="host">Host name can be a remote IP or URL of website</param>
/// <param name="port">Port to attempt to check is reachable.</param>
/// <param name="msTimeout">Timeout in milliseconds.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
Task<bool> IsRemoteReachable(string host, int port = 80, int msTimeout = 5000);
```

or for internal hosts:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests if a host name is pingable
/// </summary>
/// <param name="host">The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address (127.0.0.1)</param>
/// <param name="msTimeout">Timeout in milliseconds</param>
/// <returns></returns>
Task<bool> IsReachable(string host, int msTimeout = 5000);
```

Which I believe should be translated into:

```
IsReachable("192.168.1.107:8733", 30 * 1000);
```

Pay attention to msTimeout you have a value of 3ms there, increase it otherwise the method might return almost immediately with a negative result.

EDIT:
After a brief chat it turns out to be a library specific issue. I recommended to write the ping method on your own or to commit a bug to connectivity plugin github page.

Comment: it gives me obsolete method 
bool isRemoteReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("http://192.168.1.107/Sy‌​nchronization/rest/g‌​etclassesbrief",8733,3)

Comment: that takes string not uri

Comment: Did you read my answer? Why are you trying to use a method to check a remote host if you need to check an internal host? BTW your timeout is still 3ms.

Comment: i have not uploaded my web service online yet

Comment: Exactly, since is not available online you need to use IsReachable and not IsRemoteReachable. Another note, it might be enough to use just 192.168.1.107:8733 as your URL.

Comment: it doesnot not work, thanks @EvZ for your efforts ,do you think that i have to implement some lines on android platform adding to pcl?

Comment: Are you using a real device or an emulator? Try to open a web browser on your device/emulator and type in the url. Will it open as expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161036/discussion-between-evz-and-immortal).